# Are there achievements for the Hearthfire DLC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, achievements, skyrim-hearthfire

I just saw that the *Hearthfire* DLC for *Skyrim* [came out today](http://www.cinemablend.com/games/Skyrim-DLC-Hearthfire-Arrives-Xbox-360-46472.html) exclusively for the Xbox 360. It looks like it will only be available for 30 days before it gets pulled from the Live Marketplace. I want to have all the achievements for *Skyrim*, but I don't want to purchase this DLC if there aren't any achievements. Are there any achievements for the *Hearthfire* DLC?

**Edit:**

Graeme Nash pointed out that I misinterpreted the article. The exclusivity on Xbox 360 last for 30 days, not availability of the content itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your main question; yes. There are five achievements worth 50 points in total, details here - http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/elder-scrolls-v/achievements/

To correct your assumption, unless you have knowledge that nobody else seems to, the "30 days" that you quote is in relation to xBox exclusivity, and not to availability as a whole. That is, in the first 30 days after release no other platform will have this DLC. It should very much still be available for download on the xBox in 31 days time and beyond!

Comment: Yep - I see that the article just had it worded badly, although the intent was that the exclusivity was for 30 days. Good call.

Comment: @LENO please write a new answer if you have anything else to add.

Answer (score 2):

### Achievements

**Landowner**: Buy a plot of land.

**Land Baron**: Buy 3 plots of land.

**Architect**: Build 3 wings on a house.

**Master Architect**: Build up to 3 houses.

**Proud Parent**: Adopt a child.